# Can you use bootstrap coloumns without rows?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have seen the following code in a video:

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  </div>
</div>
```

Is this normal? Will that maintain responsiveness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the CSS file `bootstrap.css` you will be able to see that this is the code related with the `row` class:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.row:before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.row:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

There shouldn't be a problem with responsiveness, the only visible difference you could see is the padding change.